# How to reduce the space between the y-axis label and the plots

Tags: graphs

Please I need some one to help me out with this issue.
I have been able to add common axes labels to two plots I made with excel successfully. Now the problem I have is that the class file (name cit_thesis11 and approved by my university) I currently use puts extra distance between the y-axis and my graphs when I centralize the plots with the axis labels and caption. The distance is normal when I use the report or article class. What code set can I use in my tex file or class file to reduce this distance. I have included two figures to show the latex outputs when I use my class file and the report class. I have also included a working extract of my code.

[image]
[image]

```
%\documentclass[12pt,draft]{report}
\documentclass[12pt,draft]{cit_thesis11}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newsubfloat{figure}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.5cm}
\centering
\rotatebox{90}{\textcolor{red}{Y--axis label}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2.50cm\relax}%
\centering
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height-1em}{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Figures/knockho1.eps}}\ \subfloat[\label{label1}]{} \\
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height-1em}{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Figures/knockho1.eps}}\ \subfloat[\label{label2}]{}

  \vspace*{0.1cm}\textcolor{red}{X--axis label}
  \caption{This is the text that describes \protect\subref{label1} and \protect\subref{label2}.}
\end{minipage}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the `cit_thesis11` class?

Comment: Thanks hpesoj626! You can access the class file @:

[http://www.smallfiles.org/download/4776/cit_thesis11.cls.html] or [http://www.smallfiles.org/download/4778/cit_thesis11.rar.html]

Hope you can help me out. Thanks once again...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First a question, are you married to using `scale=0.4` (you could force the width of the image using `width=...`).

Here I've taken some liberties with your formatting:

```
\documentclass[12pt,draft]{cit_thesis11}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}
\newsubfloat{figure}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    {\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2.50cm+0.5cm}
        \centering
        \rotatebox{90}{\makebox[0pt]{\textcolor{red}{Y-axis label}}}
        {\begin{minipage}{6.5cm+1cm}%
            \raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height-1em}{\includegraphics[width=6.5cm]{Figures/knockho1.eps}}\ \subfloat[\label{label1}]{} \\
            \raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height-1em}{\includegraphics[width=6.5cm]{Figures/knockho1.eps}}\ \subfloat[\label{label2}]{}

            %% use hspace to center the x-axis lable and then add some space at the end for the subfloat labels.
            \vspace*{0.1cm}\hspace*{\fill}\textcolor{red}{X-axis label}\hspace*{\fill}\hspace*{0.5cm}
        \end{minipage}}%
        \caption{This is the text that describes \protect\subref{label1} and \protect\subref{label2}.}
    \end{minipage}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which renders

[image]

There are some surrounding parentheses about the boxes.  They are not necessary, but I left them there so you can easily put in an `\fbox` at the beginning of each to see how the boxes themselves look.

Some other things I've changed:

I use the `calc` package.  This makes managing the widths of the minipages a bit easier.  I've taken the `centering` out of the inner-most `minipage` because that's part of what's creating the undesirable excess space.  I've allowed `1cm` for the subfigure labels (may not be enough).  I've then inserted the same space at the end of the line for defining the *x-axis label* to give the appearance of the *x-axis label* being centered under the graphs.

The `\centering` in the `minipage` for the *y-axis label* is not necessary.  In fact that entire minipage is not necessary.  So, I've placed the *y-axis* label inside a `makebox` which I've specified to have zero width.  Then I rotate it.  This ensures that it will be centered on the box containing the two graphics (though that box also contains the *x-axis* label).  Also, I've corrected your hyphenation.  In fact, you could add some dummy space at the beginning of the `makebox` as in

```
\rotatebox{90}{\makebox[0pt]{\textcolor{red}{\rule{1\baselineskip}{0pt}Y-axis label}}}
```

which will better center the *y-axis label* to the two figures.

Comment: Thank you Ellett. Your solution was perfect. Please enjoy the rest of today. Cheers...

Comment: Since A.Ellett's answer helped you, perhaps you can thank him more appropriately by upvoting the answer by accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark).